# Blank Pages through javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I run Firefox so I started webconsole and found this on the Debugger tab:

```
Error loading this URI: Could not load the source for https://server.com/public/?p=shifts&action=view&shift_id=110.
[Exception... "Component returned failure code: 0x80470002 (NS_BASE_STREAM_CLOSED) [nsIInputStream.available]"  nsresult: "0x80470002 (NS_BASE_STREAM_CLOSED)"  location: "JS frame :: resource://devtools/shared/base-loader.js -> resource://devtools/shared/DevToolsUtils.js :: onResponse :: line 562"  data: no]
Stack: onResponse@resource://devtools/shared/base-loader.js -> resource://devtools/shared/DevToolsUtils.js:562:23
onStopRequest@resource://gre/modules/NetUtil.jsm:126:17
Line: 562, column: 0
```

can you give me hints where to find the right files to adjust?

Comment: What code are you running in order to get that error?

Comment: Why the PHP tag?

Comment: im runnig an old version of https://github.com/engelsystem/engelsystem (and yes i don't want to update :)

Comment: the php tag triggers somehow the error without it its fine